# File name conversion in Power Shell (semicolons?)

Tags: powershell, rename

I have lots of old recorded video files of my kids which I wish to convert their names and get rid of the semicolons (;) and convert it to underscores (_). The file names looks like that:
**Clip-2007-01-23 20;29;41-1.mkv**

So I tried to use the following PS method:
**`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*;*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace ';','_' }`**

But this is not working for me and after some analysis I figure out that the semicolons are not as they looks like but represented differently when looking into the file HEX representation...
Each of the semicolons (;) signs in the file name is actually [CD] [BE] hex representation. see here  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgvwf.png)  :

```
|43 6C 69 70 2D 32 30 30|37 2D 30 31 2D 32 33 30|   
|32 30 CD BE 32 39 CD BE|34 31 2D 31 2E 6D 6B 76|
```

So my question is how can I do this file rename?
Thank in advance

Comment: `$_.Name -replace '\p{Po}', '_'` should do. `Po` is the shorthand for the unicode category "Punctuation, other", which includes `U+037E`, the semicolon-looking character you've identified

Comment: perfect!
I run the following as you've suggested:  
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\p{Po}', '_' }
And the file was renamed from: Clip-2007-01-23 20;29;41-1.mkv to be: Clip-2007-01-23 20;29;41-1_mkv (the dot was replaced also) So I run the following to fix it
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '_mkv', '.mkv' }

Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice. You can exclude the dot from being matched: `-replace '[\p{Po}-[.]]', '_'`

Comment: Or just do the replacement on the file's BaseName: `Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '\p{Po}', '_'), $_.Extension }`